# pkg-resources==0.0.0 in pip freeze bug

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I am using Ubuntu 16.10, and I only installed `virtualenv` using `aptitude`. After creating a new environment, and listed installed packages using `pip freeze` I am always getting the output of

```
pkg-resources==0.0.0
```

This is causing issues when I try to deploy my Django app to other systems. What am I doing wrong?

Note that I am getting this issue only in Ubuntu and not in other distros that I tried so far.

Thanks for helping me out in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/40167445/486919 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/40167000/486919, this is a bug on Ubuntu's end and a bug report has been made at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-pip/+bug/1635463. Consider clicking on "Does this bug affect you?" followed by "Yes, it affects me" to bring this bug to the maintainers' attention.

For the time being, as stated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/40167445/486919, you can use `pip freeze` with `grep -v` to create `requirements.txt` that you can subsequently use with `pip install -r`:

```
pip freeze | grep -v "pkg-resources" > requirements.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i though i was doing something wrong on my side :)

Comment: @georoot No problem, I hadn't noticed this bug until I saw your question, so I learned something new too!

Comment: Irritatingly still a thing 2 years later. I no longer see "Does this bug affect you" at the indicated link, perhaps because of the status change to Confirmed since you posted.